# how to obfuscate spring boot application along with its internal dependencies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, proguard, obfuscation

I referred few examples online for obfuscating the spring boot + gradle app using proguard. In all those examples I could see that only application code gets obfuscated but the if the project refers to some internal jars, code from those jars remains unobfuscated.

Could anybody please provide me any working example of a spring boot project where in application code is obfuscated along with its internal jars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All code needs to be in source format instead of jars. Jars are already compiled .class files put into a zip file, and modifiying compiled code without decompiling and then obfuscating and recompiling can cause many issues when the decompiler can't translate something to source code properly.

So to make sure everything is obfuscated, have the source code of the jars in your project instead of the jars. They need to be compiled along with your project.

Comment: This solution would work. The only problem is, it creates the code duplication. The common jars are being used in multiple projects and keeping them separately in each project creates code duplication and maintenance of the common modules is difficult

Comment: @Priyanka Then make a public API jar, which only contains interfaces. Don't obfuscate that. Then have the support jars implement the the needed API jars, but then obfuscate them. Use event handlers within the API jars to have the support classes register themselves as handlers for certain things. If you want everything obfuscated you'll need to put in a lot of work and add more complexity to your code.